# put_object into s3 boto3 gives a damaged file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have a function that gets the video from S3 and does some operations on it (getting thumbnails and a short video from the original file).

I managed to download the file and do the operations. But when I try to upload it, it always gives me a damaged file. does anyone know the reason?

I'm using Python 3.6 and boto3.

My code:

```
thumb_img = './frames/0/40.png' #img thumb path
save_img = 'thumb_img_' + video_name.split('.')[0] + '.png'
session.put_object(ACL='public-read',
                   Body=thumb_img,
                   Key='PATH/TO/SUBFOLDER/' + save_img,
                   Bucket= BUCKET_NAME  )
```

Does anyone know why the file gets damaged?

Answer (score 4):

The `Body`-attribute of the `put_object` call takes "bytes or seekable file-like object" as values according to the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object), while you provide a file name.

The following code opens the file and provides the file descriptor as body instead:

```
thumb_img = './frames/0/40.png' # img thumb path
save_img = 'thumb_img_' + video_name.split('.')[0] + '.png'
with open(thumb_img, 'rb') as fd:
    session.put_object(ACL='public-read',
                       Body=fd,
                       Key='PATH/TO/SUBFOLDER/' + save_img,
                       Bucket=BUCKET_NAME)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution but I got this error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Solved with adding 'rb' to the open function. Thanks a lot man

Answer (score -2):

So the issue was that I tried to upload a file directly. `put_object` takes `bytes or seekable file-like object`. So the solution was achieved with opening the file and taking the actual body of the file.

So the code:

```
   thumb_img = './frames/1/40.png' #img thumb path
    save_img = 'thumb_img_' + video_name.split('.')[0]+'.png'

    with open(thumb_img , 'rb') as fd:
        session.put_object(ACL='public-read',
                           Body=fd,
                           Key='PATH/TO/SUBFOLDER/' + save_img,
                           Bucket=BUCKET_NAME)
```

Thanks for the help..